# Define a global variable in SPSS Modeler

Tags: analytics, spss, spss-modeler

I want to create a variable that contains `@GLOBAL_MEAN(myField)` and use it in several nodes. How can I do that in `SPSS Modeler 16.0` ?

When I add a `derive` node and create a new variable with the value `@GLOBAL_MEAN(myField)`I get the following error:

```
AEQMJ0332E: The global value '@GLOBAL_MEAN(myField)' is undefined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ! First you have to create (from outputs tab) a `Set Globals` node. Then you choose the concerned field and you can check any function you want (mean, max, min,..). Then link the node where you want to use that global value with the Set Globals node. Finaly you use the function `@GLOBAL_MEAN(myField)` in that node. The error wont appear anymore.